# Remove Older Tuples from List

Tags: python

I have a list of paths and dates:

```
  myList =  [('Y:\\Resources\\Project 1', '2016-07'),
             ('Y:\\Resources\\Project 1', '2016-08'),
             ('Y:\\Resources\\Project 2', '2014-01'),
             ('Y:\\Resources\\Project 3', '2015-12'),
             ('Y:\\Resources\\Project 3', '2016-02'),
             ('Y:\\Resources\\Project 3', '2013-08'),
             ('Y:\\Resources\\Project 4', '2016-04')]
```

I would like to remove the items with older dates and return:

```
   newList = [('Y:\\Resources\\Project 1', '2016-08'),
              ('Y:\\Resources\\Project 2', '2014-01'),
              ('Y:\\Resources\\Project 3', '2016-02'),
              ('Y:\\Resources\\Project 4', '2016-04')]
```

Comment: @Andy  It's per project

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may use `dict` to create the unique entities as:

```
>>> my_dict = {}
>>> for key, value in myList:
...     if key in my_dict:
...         if my_dict[key] < value:
...             my_dict[key] = value
...     else:
...         my_dict[key] = value
...
```

where `myList` is holding the value as is mentioned in question. In order to convert `dict` to `list` of `tuples`, do `dict.items()` as:

```
>>> new_list = my_dict.items()
>>> new_list
[('Y:\\Resources\\Project 4', '2016-04'), 
 ('Y:\\Resources\\Project 3', '2016-02'), 
 ('Y:\\Resources\\Project 2', '2014-01'), 
 ('Y:\\Resources\\Project 1', '2016-08')]
```

*Note:* `dict` do not maintain the order of elements. In case you want to maintain the order, use `collections.OrderedDict()`

Answer (score 1):

This will filter your list:

```
newList = filter(lambda x:x[1] > '2015-01', myList) # or whatever date you choose
```

Substitute your own date.

Also note this only works since your date is a string that is in a valid ISO format. Otherwise string comparison wouldn't work.

Comment: Careful... They're strings, so `>>> "2015-01" > "11000-01"
True`

Comment: @BorrajaX correct. As long as he sticks to valid dates in the form "YYYY-MM" then he will be OK though.

Comment: Comparing with something like `(int(x[1][:4]), int(x[1][5:])) > (2015, 1)` or `datetime.datetime.strptime(x[1], '%Y-%m')` is going to be safer, yeah. Either way, it's more Pythonic to use a list comprehension rather than filter and lambda: `[x for x in myList if x[1] > '2015-1']`